# How do I put vertical bars around multiple lines of maths?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I have multiple lines in maths mode, and would like to contain all them in the same vertical lines - kind of like a box around multiple lines but without the top and bottom borders. I would like for this to work in both in-line maths mode (`$...$`) and the other maths mode (`$$...$$`, I don't know what its called).

For example, how would you put vertical lines around something like this:
`$|a|\Rightarrow|b|$\\`
`$\text{....}\boxminus|a|\Rightarrow|b|$\\`
`$\text{....}\Leftrightarrow\neg|a|\vee|b|$\\`

I have searched for solutions, and tried using the bars for determinants from linear algebra, but the formatting was very inconsistent with them.

Answer (score 1):

```
I propose two easy way:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,framed}
\begin{document}
    \begin{leftbar}
        $|a|\Rightarrow|b|$\\
        $\text{....}\boxminus|a|\Rightarrow|b|$\\
        $\text{....}\Leftrightarrow\neg|a|\vee|b|$\\
    \end{leftbar}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l}
    $|a|\Rightarrow|b|$\\
    $\text{....}\boxminus|a|\Rightarrow|b|$\\
    $\text{....}\Leftrightarrow\neg|a|\vee|b|$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, it worked almost as I wanted. It did not occur to me that it is possible to use the tabular environment like this. I just have a follow-up question.

When I have something like, (should output correctly when put into a TeX editor):
```
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
 $a$\\
 $\sim b$\\
\end{tabular}
$\boxminus$
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
 $a$\\
 $\sim b$\\
\end{tabular}
```
How could I put the `$\boxminus$` between the tabulars so that it is in line with the top lines? At the moment, the `$\boxminus$` formats to be vertically in the middle.